# Objective-C Directory Picker ( OSX 10.7 )

Tags: objective-c, macos, file

So I currently have this bit of code to get a dir:

```
-(NSString *)get {      
  NSOpenPanel *gitDir = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
  NSInteger *ger = [gitDir runModalForTypes:nil];
  NSString *Directory = [gitDir directory];
  return Directory;
}
```

But it gives me errors and says it has now been depreciated.

Is there a better way for OSX 10.7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a supplement to sosborn's answer, not a replacement.

`runModalForTypes:` is deprecated, and the correct replacement is `runModal` (or `setAllowedFileTypes:` followed by `runModal`, but in this case you're passing nil for the types).

`directory` is also deprecated, and the correct replacement is `directoryURL`. (If you actually must return an `NSString` path rather than an `NSURL`, just return `[[gitDir directoryURL] path]`.)

However, what you're doing is asking the user to select a file, and then returning the directory that file is in, when what you really want is to ask the user to select a directory. To do that, you want to call `setCanChooseFiles` to `NO` and `setCanChooseDirectories` to `YES`, and then call URLs to get the directory the user selected.

Also, you're ignoring the result of `runModal` (or `runModalForTypes:`). I'm sure the compiler is warning you about the unused variable "ger", and you shouldn't just ignore warnings. If the user cancels the panel, you're going to treat that as clicking OK, and select whatever directory she happened to be in when she canceled.

Here's a better implementation, which will return the URL of the selected directory, or nil if the user canceled (or somehow managed to not select anything). Again, if you need an `NSString`, just add a "path" call to the return statement:

```
-(NSURL *)get {      
   NSOpenPanel *panel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
   [panel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO];
   [panel setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
   [panel setCanChooseFiles:NO];
   if ([panel runModal] != NSModalResponseOK) return nil;
   return [[panel URLs] lastObject];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you see a deprecation warning you should go straight to the official documentation. In this case, [the docs for NSOpenPanel](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSOpenPanel_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSOpenPanel/runModalForTypes%3a) say:

> runModalForTypes: Displays the panel and begins a modal event loop
>   that is terminated when the user clicks either OK or Cancel.
>   (Deprecated in Mac OS X v10.6. Use runModal instead. You can set
>   fileTypes using setAllowedFileTypes:.)

Comment: Since the OP didn't bother to list the warnings or say which methods were deprecated, this is a perfectly good answer, but it's not complete, because directory is deprecated also—plus, it's probably not what he wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I adapted the code by abarnert for swift. tx for the code just what I needed.

```
func askUserForDirectory() -> NSURL? {
        let myPanel:NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        myPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        myPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
        myPanel.canChooseFiles = false
        if ( myPanel.runModal() != NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton ) {
            return nil
        }
        return myPanel.URLs[0] as? NSURL
    }
```